# Determine if mailbox exists using Exchange Web Services API

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, exchangewebservices

Using the Exchange Web Services API, is it possible to determine whether a mailbox/e-mail address such as *someone@mydomain.com* exists within an organization?

If so, which is the simplest way to do this and is it possible without the use of impersonation?

**Case:** A Windows Service regularly sends e-mails to people within the organization. It does not have any explicit knowledge about their e-mail adresses. It only knows their username and assumes that their e-mail address is *username*@mydomain.com. This is true for all users except for a few that do not have mailboxes. In these cases, it should not attempt to send the e-mail in the first place.

### Solution:

As suggested by [mathieu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11629697/137471): look for user and e-mail address in Active Directory instead. This function gets the job done:

```
using System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement;
// ...

public static bool TryGetUserEmailAddress(string userName, out string email)
{
  using (PrincipalContext domainContext = 
    new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, Environment.UserDomainName))
  using (UserPrincipal user = 
    UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(domainContext, userName))
  {
    if (user != null && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user.EmailAddress))
    {
      email = user.EmailAddress;
      return true;
    }
  }
  email = null;
  return false; // user not found or no e-mail address specified
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Determining if an user has a mailbox with EWS only could be more complicated than expected, especially without impersonation.

If you're in an Active Directory domain, you should rely on the DirectoryEntry information to determine the mailbox of an user, and send email accordingly. If you got your user login, it's really easy to get the associated DirectoryEntry.

Comment: I didn't think of looking in AD, thanks! I see now that each user has a "mail" attribute, which is suitable for use in this case. However, I'm still curious to know how to do this using EWS (in the event that AD is not available) with or without impersonation.

Comment: If your AD is not available you may be in a world of trouble :D

Comment: Heh, I'm just trying to cover all the bases here. If accessing the Exchange Web Services from outside the domain, AD would not be available for such requests?

Comment: Checking if user exists in AD and examining the mail-attribute is sufficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

there is an easy way to do it by checking the user availability like the following code.
I tried this and it is working for me.

I am not sure about other cases when availability result returns error but for sure when the email is not right it does

to define your exchange service refer to this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/get-started-with-ews-managed-api-client-applications

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2007_SP1);//You version
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user1@contoso.com", "password");
service.AutodiscoverUrl("user1@contoso.com", RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);
string email = "TEST@YOUR.COM";

// Get User Availability after 6 months 
AttendeeInfo attendee = new AttendeeInfo(email);
var attnds = new List<AttendeeInfo>();
attnds.Add(attendee);
var freeTime = service.GetUserAvailability(attnds, new 
TimeWindow(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6), DateTime.Now.AddMonths(6).AddDays(1)), AvailabilityData.FreeBusyAndSuggestions);
//if you receive result with error then there is a big possibility that the email is not right
if(freetimes.AttendeesAvailability.OverallResult == ServiceResult.Error)
{
     return false;
}
return true;
```